# I want to create a parallax scrolling website of three pictures but only two scrolls work

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to create a parallex scrolling effect using javascript and html/css.
the scrolling have to apply to three picture so the 1st and 2nd picture scroll in parallex but i can't get the 2nd and the 3rd to do the same 
i'm a novice to javascript and i'm learning through doing

CSS

```
#img1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 970px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
#img2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 970px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img3{
    width: 100%;
    height: 970px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JS

```
var ypos,image,image2;
function parallex() {
    ypos = pageYOffset;
    image = document.getElementById('img1');
    image.style.top= ypos* .8 +'px';
}
function parallex2() {
    ypos = pageYOffset;
    image = document.getElementById('img2');
    image.style.zIndex=-1;
    image.style.top= ypos* .8 +'px';
}

if(screenY<=970) window.addEventListener('scroll',parallex);
else window.addEventListener('scroll',parallex2);
```

HTML

```
<img src="ny.jpg" id="img1" >
<img src="5429c32b425f183f61bf7316_new-york-city-skyline.jpg" id="img2" >
<img src="9OEWK8nMTFmqQwAFpFyn7snIGP8.jpg" id="img3">
```

Comment: You've added a jQuery tag but you're not using jQuery. May it be removed?

Comment: I think only two work because you're only set up events for img1 and img2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a three image parallax in javascript/canvas.  You might be able to adapt it to suit your needs.

```js
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
var img3 = document.getElementById('img3');
var can = document.getElementById('can');

var w = can.width = img1.width = img2.width = img3.width = 200;
var h = can.height = img1.height = img2.height = img3.height = 100;

drawImages();

// SPEEDS
var s1 = .05;
var s2 = .25;
var s3 = 2;

// POSITIONS
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var x3 = 0;

var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

function ani() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#6699CC";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); // DRAW SKY
  ctx.drawImage(img3, x1, 0); // SHOW ONLY ONE MOON

  // OTHER IMAGES REPEAT
  ctx.drawImage(img1, -w + x2, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(img1, x2, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(img2, x3, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(img2, -w + x3, 0);
  x1 += s1;
  x2 += s2;
  x3 += s3;

  if (x1 > w) x1 = 0 - w; // SHOW ONLY ONE MOON
  if (x2 > w) x2 = 0;
  if (x3 > w) x3 = 0;
  requestAnimationFrame(ani);
}
ani();

function drawImages() {
  var ctx1 = img1.getContext('2d');
  ctx1.beginPath();

  ctx1.moveTo(0, h);
  ctx1.lineTo(20, 20);
  ctx1.lineTo(40, h - 10);
  ctx1.lineTo(80, 10);
  ctx1.lineTo(120, h);
  ctx1.lineTo(160, 30);
  ctx1.lineTo(200, h);
  ctx1.fillStyle = "#996600";
  ctx1.fill();

  var ctx2 = img2.getContext('2d');
  ctx2.fillStyle = "#666666";
  ctx2.moveTo(30, h);
  ctx2.lineTo(30, 0);
  ctx2.lineTo(45, 0);
  ctx2.lineTo(45, h);
  ctx2.rect(100, 50, 25, 50);
  ctx2.rect(w - 20, 0, 20, h);
  ctx2.fill();

  var ctx3 = img3.getContext('2d');
  ctx3.moveTo(50, 50);
  ctx3.arc(25, 25, 20, 0, 360 * Math.PI / 2);
  ctx3.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
  ctx3.fill();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ACE;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="img1"></canvas>
<canvas id="img2"></canvas>
<canvas id="img3"></canvas>
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```